# How to return to initial ViewController without attaching Nav Bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I am using the Facebook API and I am trying to implement the `logout` feature. When a `UITableViewCell` is tapped, I want to return to the original login page. I tried just creating a normal segue from the VC to `ViewController.swift`(i.e. initial login page), but it attaches the `navigationBar`, which isn't what I want.

I've tried several things. This is my current code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 5 {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: KEY_UID)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: SELECTED_SPORTS)
            let loginViewController: UIViewController = ViewController()
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }
```

this just pops me back to the previous VC, which isn't what I want. I tried doing Unwind Segues, but I'm not allowed to drag onto the Exit button of the Storyboard, which is also confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `navigationBar` then just hide it.

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

This may help you brother do it this way.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{

        if indexPath.row == 5 
        {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: KEY_UID)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: SELECTED_SPORTS)
            let LoginVCOBJ = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewControllerblVC_OBJ") as! loginViewController
            self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [LoginVCOBJ]

        }
}
```